# Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I'm trying to build my app. I'm using ionic to build and now i installed the push plugin for push notifications. After i try to build i get the error : could not find com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0

I already did some research and updated in my SDK manager the Android Support Repository to rev. 32 and i have my Android Support Libary (obsolete) to rev. 23.2.1

After this it still gives the same error when i try to build with : ionic build android. What should i try next?

Comment: Update your support library to 23.4.0

Comment: i can't it doesn't show up as update option. It says installed and if i click on it it only shows the option remove package

Comment: Open your app modules gradle.build file and change the line `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'` to `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'`

Comment: it does say: // GENERATED FILE! DO NOT EDIT!, and i find this one compile "com.android.support:support-v13:23+" , but not the v4:23.2.1. So i changed the support-v13:23+ . The same error still occurs, but the file is changed to its original state

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"I installed revision 32 of Android Support Repository on the package service"

Comment: Link broken, 404

Answer (score 0):

Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1
I had a similar case, the error I was given was because the plugin version of the camera was not compatible, I deleted the camera and compiled but when I installed it again the cordova-plugin-camera version 2.4.1 had the error again.
Then enter the page: github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/releases#start-of-content

Download and unzip the file (cordova-plugin-camera version 2.3.0 rel) then go to Complements -> Custom and select the uncompressed file and compile perfectly

Plugin breaking changes caused by Cordova 6.0.0 / Cordova Android 5.0.0
Android Marshmallow introduced new security features that have resulted in breaking changes to Cordova itself and by extension core plugins including:

cordova-plugin-camera
cordova-plugin-geolocation
cordova-plugin-contacts
cordova-plugin-file
cordova-plugin-media

https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tutorial-cordova-5-readme/